# Upgrading COM call-back interface

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl, dcom

We have a problem with COM Connection point callback interfaces

In our Sample.idl we have few call-back interfaces ISomeEvents

```
interface ISomeEvents : IUnknown
{
         HRESULT Event1([in]int nData);
         HRESULT Event2([in]int nData);
         HRESULT Event3([in]int nData);
}

And in the CoClass we have the following statement 
coclass MyComp
{
    [default] interface IMyInterface;
    interface IMyInterFace2;
    [default, source] interface ISomeEvents;
};
```

Now whenever we add new interfaces as part of enhancement,this does not break the existing client, but if the enhancement has 
Any modifications to call-back then we endup updating the interface ISomeEvents, which is breaking existing clients, we are forced to do this because I think we can 
Have only one [defaut,source] Interface.

Can anyone tell me What is the workaround for this?

Regards
tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing a COM object where the client(s) are live/in production, you really shouldn't change an existing interface, any interface. That has always been the fundamental rule of COM development: "interfaces are immutable"; exceptions are made during early development, of course.

(Here's a quote for example: "COM interfaces are immutable. You cannot define a new version of an old interface and give it the same identifier." ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688484(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Look up "interfaces are immutable" on the web for plenty more)

In this case, you should create new interfaces `ISomeEvents2`, `ISomeEvents3`, so on as needed, and have those interfaces inherit from the previous version. Make the new interface your new default source.

```
interface ISomeEvents1 : ISomeEvents
{
    /* new enhanced events here, for use by newly compiled clients */
}
```

Eventually, if you need more changes:

```
interface ISomeEvents2 : ISomeEvents1
{
    /* Even newer enhanced events here, for even newer clients */
}
```

And so on.

Comment: we have a COM Interop layer and the COM components and we have a requirement where the COM dlls should be backward compatible, now if the default source interface is changed, can you tell me how this will be backward compatible, because the older interop layer will have no idea about ISomeEvents2

Comment: I think that should be fine. Older clients using the old interop can never use the new functionality no matter what you do. The old interop should in fact be able to continue to implement and use `ISomeEvents` just fine. Only newer clients implementing `ISomeEvents2` would use the extra members. (But I haven't done COM events in a decade; if you think this is wrong, please let me know.)

Comment: By making the Default source Interface as ISomeEvents2, you are breaking the older clients, COM is supposed to be version compatible. if you have an Interface say IMyInterface and later you add a new Interface IMyInterface2, the older client application can continue to use the new DLL and use IMyInterface2, this not breaking  clients but with respect to Source Interfaces, i think this is a problem, what is the solution for this

Comment: I don't believe it breaks anything. Interfaces are immutable, but coclasses are not. You could always specify multiple source interfaces in IDL, and the [default] attribute just marks your preferred one. The interop code was built using the old preference, but that just means that it chooses to pass the UUID of `ISomeEvent` (rather than `ISomeEvent2`'s) to `IConnectionPointContainer::FindConnectionPoint()` and your object should be able to provide a suitable `IConnectionPoint` for it. As long as you keep accepting `ISomeEvent` as a valid sink interface, your client code should be happy.

Comment: However, I wonder if you need to explicitly specify both `ISomeEvents` and `ISomeEvents2` as [source]s, instead of relying just on the inheritance. I wouldn't be surprised if you do.